# Does broadFileSystemAccess capability require Company account?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge

I asked few months ago for the broadFileSystemAccess capability from developer support. They said I need to switch my account to a company account and move all my apps into it, in order to request for this capability. I prefer to avoid this approach for now.

Recently I noticed changes on the capability request process on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) page but there is still nothing there to state such limitation for individual accounts. I would like to know if anyone here (from MS perhaps) has more information to make sure I've got correct information.

I have two storage utility apps, it completely makes sense for them to use this capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does broadFileSystemAccess capability require Company account?

The follow segment does not exit in the `BroadFileSystemAccess` capability description, So the company accounts are not required.

> We do not recommend declaring this capability in apps submitted to the Store. For most developers, use of this capability will not be approved.

But, it is restricted capability. If your app declares any restricted capabilities, you must provide info during the [app submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-submissions) process in order to be approved to publish the app to the Microsoft Store. You provide this info on the [Submission options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-submission-options#restricted-capabilities) page of your submission, explaining how your app uses each restricted capability that it declares.

Comment: OK i'll go ahead for a submission later then I will update his question. I see zero integrity in the way MS is dealing with this permissions btw.

Comment: hi @MehrzadChehraz If the answer has resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew That's for the reminder. As I a commented above, I'm going to update the question after I submit an update with the required permission.

Comment: hi @MehrzadChehraz does the store accept your submit?

Comment: Hi, I haven't submitted yet. I need to put effort to use the new capability. It's delayed because I don't know if they accept it or not and the risk of wasting my time. I will update the question when I submit it.

Comment: Yeap, please feel free to tell me the result.

Comment: Have you guys actually been able to use broadFileSystemAccess ?  It is not recognized by VS2017.

Comment: Yep, `BroadFileSystemAccess` capability works in my side.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I submitted one of the apps which requires the broadFileSystemAccess capability and it has been accepted.